# EditText hint keep showing

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-textinputlayout

I have an **activity_edit_profile.xml** layout which embeds a fragment, but the EditText hint keeps displaying permanently. How do I get rid of the hint when the EditText field is on focus or inserting text?

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:id="@+id/DrawerLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            tools:context="com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.sample.EditProfileActivity"
            tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame">

            <include layout="@layout/fragment_edit_profile"/>

     </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

In the **fragment_edit_profile.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:padding="16dp"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              tools:context="com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.sample.EditProfileActivity$PlaceholderFragment">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:theme="@style/TextLabel">

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="First Name"
                android:inputType="textCapWords"
                android:nextFocusDown="@+id/register_input_lastname"
                />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:theme="@style/TextLabel">

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/register_input_lastname"
                android:hint="Last Name"
                android:inputType="textCapWords"/>
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:theme="@style/TextLabel">

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Email"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress" />
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:theme="@style/TextLabel">

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Password"
            android:inputType="textPassword" />
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:theme="@style/TextLabel">

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="Country Code"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:nextFocusDown="@+id/mobile_number"/>

        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:theme="@style/TextLabel">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/mobile_number"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="Mobile"
                android:inputType="phone"/>

        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

The editText hint keeps displaying and overlapping with the textInput.

[image]

[EDIT]

Here's the TextLabel style:

```
<style name="TextLabel" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance">
    <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/half_black</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">14dp</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/ColorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/ColorPrimary</item>
</style>
```

Comment: It looks problem is with your style android:theme="@style/TextLabel" can you post the code?
Remove style and check it will work.

Comment: I have attached the theme style.

Answer (score 0):

You can attach focusChangeListener to your `EditText` fields.

Let's take the example of `First Name`.  Assign it the id `firstName`. Now, when it comes into focus, set the hint text as an empty string. When it loses focus, change the hint text back to `First Name`:

```
EditText firstName = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.firstName);
firstName.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
        if(hasFocus) {
            firstName.setHint("");
        }
        else {
            firstName.setHint("First Name");
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably problem is with your theme you are setting for the `TextInputLayout` your style should look like-

```
    <style name="AppTheme.EditText">
        <item name="colorPrimary">#FF4081</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#3F51B5</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">#303F9F</item>
    </style>
```

Comment: Thanks. But it does not seem to be a styling problem. I tried applying your style, color changes but the hint text remains permanently.

Answer (score -1):

Remove your TextInputLayout Widget. Add Only EditText.

```
   <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="First Name"
            android:inputType="textCapWords"
            android:nextFocusDown="@+id/register_input_lastname"
            />
```